# For Loops in Python to read Long URL from shortened URL

Tags: python, for-loop, urllib2

I'm a python beginner and struggling with the loop function. If I run the code I just receive the long URL for the last entry. Any ideas? Thanks

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

for x in ('civ8JgUVEH','iSROHi98ag','taZ38yUBOb'):
  shortURL = 'http://t.co/' + str(x)
output = urllib2.urlopen(shortURL)

print output.url
```

Answer (score 2):

You are reassigning your variable every time before actually opening or printing the URL. You need to indent your code so that assigning and printing the `output` variable is done within the for loop:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

for x in ('civ8JgUVEH','iSROHi98ag','taZ38yUBOb'):
  shortURL = 'http://t.co/' + str(x)
  output = urllib2.urlopen(shortURL)

  print output.url
```

Comment: @LucasKauffman well OP can't actually upvote **yet**, but after 15 mins your answer may be [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)